# generating integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, partitions

*Mathematica* can generate integer partitions of an integer $N$. For example, `IntegerPartitions[4]` quickly gives

```
{{4}, {3, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

This is nice, but I wish to generate a partition given as $[N_1,N_2,\ldots,]$
with $\sum_{i}i N_i=N$, where $N_i$ counts the number of $i$ in the partition.
For example, in the above-mentioned example of $N=4$, we would have

```
{{0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0, 0}}
```

How could I generate this with *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
myIP[int_] := Block[{ip = IntegerPartitions[int], r},
  r = Range[1, int];
  Tally[Join[r, #]][[All, 2]] - 1 & /@ ip]
```

Comment: Thank you! This also works! In my computer your code is fastest at say N=35.

Comment: Why not `r = Range[int]`?

Comment: @J.M. No reason, came from a routine I use for restricted partitions (so min/max may not be 1/arg)...

Answer (score 14):

I needed to do this sometime ago while investigating Bell polynomial analogs. Normally, you'd do

```
FrobeniusSolve[Range[n], n]
```

but the fastest variation (and quite compact, too!) I found was

```
Outer[Count, IntegerPartitions[n], Range[n], 1]
```

---

### A different approach

Some undocumented magic is needed for this approach; in particular, with the system setting [`"SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203344) that adds up entries in duplicate positions, we can write something like this:

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> 1}];
cp[n_Integer?Positive] := SparseArray[Flatten[MapIndexed[
        Thread[Transpose[PadRight[{#2, #1}, Automatic, #2]] -> 1] &, 
        IntegerPartitions[n]]]]
```

This is slightly faster than my previous approach, but still slower than ciao's.

---

Finally, ciao's code can be optimized slightly, with a modest gain in speed:

```
myIP2[n_Integer?Positive] := Block[{r = Range[n], tmp},
      tmp = Tally[Join[r, #]] & /@ IntegerPartitions[n];
      tmp[[All, All, 2]] - 1]
```

Comment: Very nice with `Outer`. +1

Comment: Thank you so much! This is indeed compact and fast.

Comment: `MyIP` is faster in my tests... yours?

Comment: @ciao, yes, yours seems to edge out mine for large integers. I came up with yet another variation, tho; wait...

Comment: Nice opts... +1

Answer (score 7):

```
Reverse@GroupTheory`Tools`IntegerPartitionCounts[4]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0, 0}}

```
GroupTheory`Tools`IntegerPartitionCounts[70] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.48625, 4087968}

Answer (score 6):

```
nCountPartitions[int_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{partitions = IntegerPartitions[int], selectList},
  selectList = Function[{i}, Select[# == i &]] /@ Range[int];
  Length /@ Through[selectList[#]] & /@ partitions
  ]

nCountPartitions[4]
(* {{0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

`selectList` is a list of `Select` functions, one for each possible integer.

```
Function[{i}, Select[# == i &]] /@ Range[4]
(* {Select[#1 == 1 &], Select[#1 == 2 &], Select[#1 == 3 &], Select[#1 == 4 &]} *)
```

Each partition is passed `Through` to this list of functions that select out their matches. The `Length` of these select list are then taken.